# Oauth2 for Authorization and Authentication?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid-connect

Can Oauth2 be used for *authorization* and *authentication*?

As I understand it, Oauth2 *authorizes* a consumer application to access user information from providers (e.g. Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc).

But can Oauth2 be used to *authenticate* a user? For example, suppose we have an app comprised of native mobile frontends and a backend api - can Oauth2 be used to valid and maintain *authentication* on top of the *authorization* from providers like Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc?

If yes, how? For example, do we persistent the auth token and use it as a session token? Or is OpenId Connect required for *authenticating* users to a "consumer" app via third-party providers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 in its spec-compliant form cannot be used for user authentication. Having said that, one can develop an extension to OAuth 2.0 that would allow for user authentication. Some providers, e.g. Facebook, have done just that.

But there is also a standardized extension of OAuth 2.0 that allows for user authentication, called OpenID Connect. OpenID Connect is required indeed if you want to authenticate users to a consumer app via 3rd party providers in a *standardized* way. The token format of OpenID Connect is a JWT and the token itself is called `id_token`. You may use an `id_token` as a session token.

For an extensive article on OAuth 2.0 and user authentication see http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Comment: And see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/GettingStarted and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect for Google APIs.